# How to view the contents of an Android APK file?

Tags: android, apk

Is there a way to extract and view the content of an .apk file?

Comment: Check out [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).

Comment: apktool moved to https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Actually the apk file is just a zip archive, so you can try to rename the file to `theappname.apk.zip` and extract it with any zip utility (e.g. 7zip).

The `androidmanifest.xml` file and the resources will be extracted and can be viewed whereas the source code is not in the package - just the compiled .dex file ("Dalvik Executable")

Comment: The dalvik file can be converted to jar using dex2jar utility and then can be opened by any java decompiler tool.

Answer (score 53):

It's shipped with Android Studio now.
Just go to **Build/Analyze APK...** then select your APK :)

[image]

Answer (score 22):

While unzipping will reveal the resources, the `AndroidManifest.xml` will be encoded. [`apktool`](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) can – among lots of other things – also decode this file.

To decode the application `App.apk` into the folder `App`, run

```
apktool decode App.apk App
```

`apktool` is not included in the official Android SDK, but available using most packet repositories.

Comment: You have to add `-o` to the command, otherwise, it thinks `App` is an input file, reporting the error: "Input file (App) was not found or was not readable". Proper command: `apktool decode App.apk -o App`.

Answer (score 12):

There is also [zzos](https://github.com/Shachar/Lingnu-Android-Tools). (Full disclosure: I wrote it). It only decompiles the actual resources, not the dex part ([baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/), which I did not write, does an excellent job of handling that part).

Zzos is much less known than apktool, but there are some APKs that are better handled by it (and vice versa - more on that later). Mostly, APKs containing custom resource types (not modifiers) were not handled by apktool the last time I checked, and are handled by zzos. There are also some cases with escaping that zzos handles better.

On the negative side of things, zzos (current version) requires a few support tools to install. It is written in perl (as opposed to APKTool, which is written in Java), and uses aapt for the actual decompilation. It also does not decompile attrib resources yet (which APKTool does).

The meaning of the name is "aapt", Android's resource compiler, shifted down one letter.

Answer (score 9):

You have several tools available:

- [Aapt](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) (which is part of the Android SDK)

  ```
  $ aapt dump badging MyApk.apk
  $ aapt dump permissions MyApk.apk
  $ aapt dump xmltree MyApk.apk
  ```
- [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

  ```
  $ java -jar apktool.jar -q decode -f MyApk.apk -o myOutputDir
  ```
- [Android Multitool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2326604)
- Apk Viewer
- [ApkShellext](https://code.google.com/p/apkshellext/)
- [Dex2Jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar)

  ```
  $ dex2jar/d2j-dex2jar.sh -f MyApk.apk -o myOutputDir/MyApk.jar
  ```
- [NinjaDroid](https://github.com/rovellipaolo/NinjaDroid)

  ```
  $ ninjadroid MyApk.apk
  $ ninjadroid MyApk.apk --all --extract myOutputDir/
  ```
- [AXMLParser](https://github.com/appknox/pyaxmlparser)

  ```
  $ apkinfo MyApk.apk
  ```

Answer (score 8):

**`unzip my.apk`**

This does the trick from the Linux command line since the APK format is just a ZIP file on the top.

Answer (score 8):

**4 suggested ways to open apk files:**

1.open apk file by [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) (For Photo,java code and analyze size) ***the best way***

[image]

2.open by applications winRar,7zip,etc (Just to see photos and ...)

3.use website [javadecompilers](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) (For Photo and java code)

4.use [APK Tools](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) (For Photo and java code)

Answer (score 3):

**There is a online decompiler for android apks**

[**http://www.decompileandroid.com/**](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

Upload apk from local machine

Wait some moments

download source code in zip format.

Unzip it, you can view all resources correctly but all java files are not correctly decompiled.

For full detail [**visit this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Answer (score 3):

In case of **Hybrid apps** developed using cordova and angularjs, you can:

**1)** Rename the .apk file to .zip 
**2)** Extract/Unzip the contents 
**3)** In the assets folder you will get the www folder

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your reason for wanting to extract the APK, APK Analyzer  might be sufficient. It shows you directories, and file sizes. It also shows method counts grouped by package that you can drill down into.

APK Analyzer is built into Android Studio. You can access it from the top menu, Build -> Analyze APK.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Jadx - https://github.com/skylot/jadx. I have used all the tools mentioned in this page and found that Jadx works the best. The manifest file and other class files are converted to readable format as much as possible by this tool.

PS - http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk also uses the jadx decompiler to do the same work online. Simpler if you want to unarchive a single apk.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The [APK Scanner](https://github.com/apk-spectrum/apk-scanner/releases) can be show the information of APK file on PC.
also, can be pull an apk file from the android device.
And can be link to other tools.(JADX-GUI, JD-GUI...)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0A86.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the contents of an APK file within the Android device itself, which helps a lot in debugging.

All files including the manifest of an app can be viewed and also shared using email, cloud etc., no rooting required. App is available from:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dasmic.android.apkpeek

Disclaimer: I am the author of this app.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it with peazip after I couldn't rename file extension.