# Flutter sample app size

Tags: flutter

On Android flutter sample app (release version) is 13 MB app size + 12 MB data. Why there is 12 MB of data? On iOS the app size is even 47 MB (i hope that it is due some multi architecture but may be it is final size)

Answer (score 0):

[**How big is the Flutter engine?**](https://flutter.io/faq/#how-big-is-the-flutter-engine)

> For this simple app, the core engine is approximately 3.3MB
>   (compressed), the framework + app code is approximately 1.25MB
>   (compressed), the LICENSE file (contained in app.flx) is 55k
>   (compressed), necessary Java code (classes.dex) is 40k (compressed),
>   and there is approximately 2.1MB of (compressed) ICU data.

Comment: so why the sample is 13 + 12 MB then

Comment: what do you mean by sample app? is it the boilerplate app ?

Comment: For the moment it's just 4.7 mb

Comment: @Raouf Rahiche 4.7 mb for what - the Android aab? What about iOS? I think they've made is smaller but the basic app on iOS is 30MB.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Raouf's answer for the iOS version:

Apple uses [App Thinning](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f) when your app is uploaded to the app store. So it will drastically loose size.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size).

Comment: even with bitcode disabled? sample ios app has AFAIK  bitcode disabled. but still the multiple architectures can be maybe splitted (i am not sure)

Comment: Yes, even with bitcode disabled it takes much space. You may be able to compile the app in xcode for just one architecture but I guess that wouldn't make much sense.