# Is Kotlin Plugin required for the Flutter app?

Tags: kotlin, flutter

I am developing an app in Flutter which require plugins like

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3  
  gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
  firebase_storage_image: ^0.4.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+6
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  google_map : any
```

Do I require Kotlin Support?

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

As my app is gaining size It is now 50 MB, thought removing Kotlin Support may minimize the app size.

Comment: There is no need of kotlin support and generally when you are installing apps in flutter it gains size more than 50 mb to 300 mb, but you can see actual size of your app by generating its apk. This extra size gives you feature of Hot-Reload in Flutter.

Comment: oh thanks..So I would get minimal apk size while release on GooglePlay?

Comment: yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size/49065366

Comment: Oh My God! it is working App size is reduced to 8.5MB,after using Flutter build apk.