# Flutter project size is really huge. How to reduce it?

Tags: flutter, dart, project, filesize

I just made a Hello World App, but the file size is really **big**.
Is there a way to reduce project file size?

Comment: The file size of *what*? Did you build for Android? iOS? Web? Desktop (which one?). How big *is* you file and what does your app look like?

Comment: Do you mean the size of the project on your computer or the app on your phone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter apps are too big in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size)

Comment: I mean the project file size , not the apk size

Comment: I too facing same issue. Basic project size is 4mb. If i install cocoapods for iOS, its huge project size. It is very difficult to share source code to others if project size is huge

Answer (score 7):

I think you are talking about project size, not apk or ipa file size. For basic flutter project, size is within 10MB. When we run cocoapods for iOS, all dependencies will download and project size increases to more than 500MB or 1GB also. But this causes for only iOS, not android.

> pod deintegrate

did the trick to remove all dependencies whenever you want to distribute source code.

Again you can install all dependencies with below command in ios folder

> pod install

Step 1 : flutter clean

Step 2 : in iOS folder of project, pod deintegrate.

Step 3 : For install again, flutter pub get

Step 4 : in iOS folder of project, pod install

Step 5 : flutter build ios (only if you got build errors)

Step 6 : then run app in Xcode or VSCode or Android studio by selecting simulator or real device.

This process will reduce project size and can able to distribute source code via mail.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are talking about Android Apk. It is preferred to get `appbundle`, but if you want to get an `apk`, you should build your `apk` with `--split-per-abi`.

`flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

You can read the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) carefully.

> Removing the --split-per-abi flag results in a fat APK that contains your code compiled for all the target ABIs. **Such APKs are larger in size** than their split counterparts, causing the user to download native binaries that are not applicable to their device’s architecture.

Comment: I think he is talking about project size, not apk or ipa file size. I too facing same issue. Basic project size is 4mb. If i install cocoapods for iOS, its huge project size. It is very difficult to share source code to others if project size is huge.

Comment: Already tried twice, not solved my issue and app size. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think so you took apk file from `Your_project\build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`
If so definitely your apk size will be larger.

STEP 1 : In your project terminal, type `flutter build apk` and then press Enter.

STEP 2 : And then after completion of process. Get into `Your_project\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk`
Choose the `app-release.apk`, this file size will be smaller now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command. I was also searching for the answer of this and later found this command.

`flutter build apk --release --tree-shake-icons --split-per-abi`

for explanation, refer this link https://suryadevsingh24032000.medium.com/size-matters-reducing-flutter-app-size-best-practices-ca992207782