# My Apk size getting much large after upgrading flutter to latest

Tags: flutter

Im building an **apk** and the size is too large bcz i just created a ui till now and the size is **49mb** there is huge differnece .

[image]

**in this image** the upper apk size is **22mb** which build is created 7months ago but now i reopen and just created build again the size is **47mb** somehow facing this issue in all apps the size is getting larger.

Comment: before running the ``flutter build`` cmd run ``flutter clean`` cmd. You should see the size difference. Also, build app bundle instead of apk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size

Comment: brother if i do new build then also same huge size there isnt in app just simple 10pages ui with less assets