# Flutter app size is big because of google_ml_kit, it almost crossed 150 mb in size

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating Flutter paraphrasing app but my app size is too big, I don't know why?

App is used for paraphrasing, the text user can enter text, speak or extract text from file. We translate and paraphrase the text.
I created this for my software house but i don't know why app size is too big. I am not even using static assets still app size is **158MB**

```
name: paraphrase_and_translate
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  speech_to_text: ^5.5.0
  google_ml_kit: ^0.11.0
  camera: ^0.9.7+1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  translator: ^0.1.7
  clipboard: ^0.1.2+8
  pdf_text: ^0.5.0
  file_picker: ^4.6.1
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  flex_color_scheme: ^5.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  dio: ^4.0.6
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.0.8
  language_picker: ^0.4.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  flutter_tts: ^3.5.0
  simple_speed_dial: ^0.1.7
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.3.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/new.png
    - assets/images/parapharse.png
    - assets/images/icon.png
```

**This is my pubspec.yaml file.
images are only 2 mbs only**

```
Running "flutter pub get" in paraphrase_and_translate...
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 8 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (159.1MB).
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter apps are too big in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064969/flutter-apps-are-too-big-in-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be the package `google_ml_kit` increse the build size.

Try using any specific package that useful to you, mentioned in dependencies of the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit).

[image: Dependencies]

All these [packages](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit#features) are included in the google_ml_kit package. Avoid using unwanted packages.

For instance use [google_mlkit_text_recognition](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_text_recognition) if you are using text recognition alone instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

If DevTools is already connected to a running application, navigate to the “App Size” tab.
Check which module is using what size and manage accordingly, also only use required packages and removed unnecessary assets or resize them if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Also: don't use an APK, but an appbundle for Android. It build way smaller binaries. For this, use:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android > app > build.gradle and set the minSdkVersion to 22

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.app"
        minSdkVersion 22  // set this to min 22
        targetSdkVersion 31

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).