# Is there a way to see what's taking up how much space in a Flutter app release build?

Tags: android, flutter

I uploaded my Flutter app bundle to Google Play today and I found that the estimated download size has quadrupled in size since last time. I haven't added much so I don't know what's taking up that much space. It went from ~10MB to ~40MB. Is there a way to see what's taking up how much space, so I can understand what's going on, regarding app download size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested but could try and analyze built apk: [How to view the contents of an Android APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599210/how-to-view-the-contents-of-an-android-apk-file)

And cheak resources(images, stuff from libraries) https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size#ios

Comment: Thanks! Building an apk, extracting it, and using JDiskReport to analyze file contents was my solution. It turns out that even though I deleted some old assets that I was testing at the time, flutter cache kept them and included them in my release build. Running `flutter clean` solved the issue and the apk is back to normal! I used `flutter build apk --target-platform=android-arm` to build the apk and `flutter build appbundle` to build the appbundle for Google Play.