# How to view app content with the help of apk?

Tags: java, android, file, apk, storage

just experimenting with something. Is it possible to view the content of the app with the help of APK? For example, is it possible that I get to locate the text/content in the apk code?
See photo for example (also using wattpad as an example, i know there is a wattpad downloader and also universal copy but i was wondering if this can be located in apk): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW6OZ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view the contents of an Android APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599210/how-to-view-the-contents-of-an-android-apk-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the apk file name and change the extension to .zip
Then unzip the folder to view the contents.